# How do I make a google query that selects for row?

Tags: mysql, excel, google-sheets

**Example:**

If my data set is

```
A B C
1 2 3
5 6 7
4 5 6
```

I could have "1", "5" and "4" show up by typing =query(A:C, `select A`).

I could have "1" and "4" show up by typing =query(A:C, `select A where B < 6`).

Lets say I wanted to query only entries that appeared after a certain row. In this case, `row 3` is **4, 5, 6**. So if I want only results that are row 3 or below, I could add a fourth column `D` somewhere, fill `column D` with `=row()`, and then have only **** show up by typing

=query(A:C, `select A where D >= 3`).

But I don't want to have to add a fourth column somewhere and fill it with the `=row()` formula. The query should be able to do this on its own.

Comment: But you have to get data based on some order. What's that order?

Comment: =query(dataSet, selectorString) returns the data as is. you don't need to specify an order.

Answer (score 1):

**Query parametres**

try:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select * offset 2",0)
```

`offset` parameter is zero base:

- 0 -- start from row 1
- 1 -- start from row 2
- 2 -- start from row 3
- so on

You may find more usuful [query tips here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). Use special words: `offset`, `limit`, `skipping`. For example, to select only odd rows use:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select * skipping 2",0)
```

---

**Filter function**

To have full control of rows you select, use this construction:

- `=filter(A:C,isodd(row(A:C)))` -- only odd rows
- `=filter(A:C,row(A:C)=3)` -- only 3-d row
- `=filter(A:C,row(A:C)>=3)` -- all rows >= 3-d row
- `=query(filter(A:C,row(A:C)>=3),"select *")` use filter + query

Comment: doesnt do what I want it to do. this takes whatever results would appear, then shows those results omitting the first x. I need it to actually filter by what row the result appears in.

Comment: It's nor clear for me, what result are you willing to get. Please provide more example. If you want only third row, there're different ways to accomplish the task. One is to use query + offset + limit, and you also may use filter function.

Comment: I want to be able to filter by what row the data is in. Lets say my data set is the same as the given example, but I only want to select data from odd rows. So I want to type something like "select * where data.row()%2=1". if queried on the data above, it would return 123 and 456.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had an issue like this, and here is what I did.  I made a virtual column.

=query(A:C, select A where D >= 3)  would then be something like
=query({A:C, ROW(A:C)}, "Select Col1 where Col4 >=3")

You have to make an array to query a column you do not want in your sheet.  In doing so you can no longer use Column letters, so then A, B, C then becomes Col1, Col2, Col3 and so on.